# Are the two definitions of differentiable structure on $M$ not equivalent?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

The following pages are from Lee's "Introduction to smooth manifolds".

[image]

[image]

[image]

The following pages are from Varadarajan's "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Their Representations".

[image]

[image]

I think the two definitions of ($C^\infty$) differentiable structure on $M$ in the two books are not equivalent, isn't it?

Comment: You should point out specifics of where you think that the two definitions differ. Giving an example of a structure which satisfies one set of axioms but not the other would be very helpful (but perhaps not doable).

Comment: The two definitions are quite different and it's not clear how to connect one to the other, so I think the question is justified.